# A Function to return just the value from a KeyValuePair

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-4.0, keyvaluepair

I have the following function which gets a series of KVP's up front from a database and now I want to write a function that will take an Integer value as its argument and return the matching String value. What's the best way of doing this please?

```
Private Function GetReasons() As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
    Dim returnValue As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(SCRGlobals.ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT CODE, DESC FROM ltblDELAY", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim c As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While c.Read
            returnValue.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(c("CODE"), c("DESC")))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        Common.LogError(ex, True, False)
    Finally
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: In general you should set [`OPTION STRICT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to `On`.

Comment: Use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write your own function.

```
Dim l As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
l = GetReasons()
Dim intKey as Integer = 1 '<-- whatever value you want to look up.
'This is your function...
Dim strValue as String = l.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key).Item(intKey).Value
```

Actually, you could wrap this in your own function (and make it more robust):

```
Private Function GetValue(l As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)), key As Integer)
    Dim d As Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)) = l.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key)
    If d.ContainsKey(key) Then
        Return d.Item(key).Value
    Else
        'Default value or error message
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: what is the intKey value?

Comment: That's the integer value argument that you wanted for your function.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it as filter-parameter to the database: `WHERE CODE=@Code`:

```
Private Function GetReasons(code As Int32) As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
    Dim returnValue As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT CODE, DESC FROM ltblDELAY WHERE CODE=@Code", con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = code
                con.Open()
                Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While rd.Read()
                        Dim desc = rd.GetString(1)
                        returnValue.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Int32, String)(code, desc))
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Common.LogError(ex, True, False)
    End Try
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

Note that i've used also the `Using`-statement to ensure that all objects that might contain unmanaged resources(like the connection) are getting disposed property(even on error). That will also close the connection.

I've also used `SqlDatareader.GetString` instead of the indexer which returns `Object`. Your code won't compile with [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) which i strongly recommend.

---

Since you're only interested in the description which is a string, return a `List(Of String)`:

```
Private Function GetReasons(code As Int32) As List(Of String)
    Dim returnValue As New List(Of String)
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT CODE, DESC FROM ltblDELAY WHERE CODE=@Code", con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = code
                con.Open()
                Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While rd.Read()
                        Dim desc = rd.GetString(1)
                        returnValue.Add(desc)
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Common.LogError(ex, True, False)
    End Try
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: sorry if i'm missing something, but this is returning the whole list of strings where as i just want the specific string value matching the passed in code value?

Comment: @PaulStevens: i have filtered in the database: `WHERE CODE=@Code`. It's always better to filter in the database than to select all data and filter at the client.